# How to calculate camera matrix in self-camera calibration in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, projection, camera-calibration, calibration

My goal is to place images (ads) around a volleyball field in a video. The ad needs to have the correct perspective distortion and I do not have access to the camera model so I need to do self-camera calibration (I cannot use checkerboard etc.). I will use a reference points with known sizes in world coordinates. Thus, I'm using the rectangular area close to the net. I chose the corners of this area from a picture containing a top-down view of a volleyball field (model image representing the field) and corresponding points from the first frame, which are called **movingPoints_f1**, of the video and I'm tracking those points throughout the video by applying a line detection algorithm, which are called **closest_points**. Then, I concatenate those points in the 3rd dimension:

```
imgPoints = cat(3, closest_points, movingPoints_f1)
```

Then calculated the camera parameters like this:

```
cameraParams = estimateCameraParameters( imgPoints, fixedPoints)
```

where *fixedPoints* are coordinates from the model of volleyball court.

After that I've calculated the rotation matrix and translation vector for every frame -because the camera's position is changing in the world coordinates (it is panning)- and corresponding camera matrix like this:

```
[rotationMatrix,translationVector] = extrinsics( closest_points,fixedPoints,cameraParams)
camMat = cameraMatrix(cameraParams,rotationMatrix,translationVector);
```

Now, *camMat* can be used to map points from world coordinates to image coordinates according to this documentation https://nl.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/camera-calibration.html using the below formula:

[image: mapping points from world coordinates to image coordinates]

I'm calculating the corresponding image points for every pixel of the ad (*row* and *column* are changing with two for statements):

```
fieldCoord = topLeftCorner+[column row];
world_hmg = [fieldCoord 0 1];
scaled_img_coordinates_hmg = double(world_hmg) * camMat;
img_coordinates_hmg = 1/scaled_img_coordinates_hmg(3) * scaled_img_coordinates_hmg;
img_coordinates_inhmg = img_coordinates_hmg(1:2);
```

I'm using 0 as Z coordinates because the ad is planar in the world coordinates. And also I'm converting the points from homogeneous coordinates to inhomogeneous coordinates. After that, I basically copy the pixels from ad to the field:

```
fieldAd(int64(img_coordinates_inhmg(2)), int64(img_coordinates_inhmg(1)),:) = adImg(row, column,:);
```

However, when I do forward mapping for every pixel in the ad, the ad contains a lot of wholes and it's not shown very well.

I've read that backward mapping overcomes this issue (wholes and overlapping points) but *camMat* is 4x3 matrix and thereby is singular matrix. I cannot compute the inverse of it to do backward mapping.

How can  I do backward mapping? Or is there another way to embed the ad into the court properly?

Comment: You do not need the camera matrix for that. You can just calculate a perspective transformation for every frame and then apply it to the ad images.

Comment: By perspective transformation, I assume you mean projective transformation @Nikos : How can I do that if I have a single frame and the ad? Afaik, in order to apply projective transform you need to have 4 pair of points from two different images so that you can calculate the homography matrix. But in my case, I have only one frame and the ad?

Comment: You are right. I meant to write projective transformation. To compute the homography you simply you as source coordinates four corners of the ad and for the destination you select four points on the frame. The source coordinates are easily calculated using the ad's image dimensions [(0,0),(0,height),(width,0),(width,height)].

Comment: Sorry but it won't work @Nikos. Here is why: If you choose 4 corners , where the ad needs to be, from the frame, then it won't have correct perspective because you're manually choosing where(and at which shape) the ad needs to appear in the frames.

Comment: If what you want to achieve is what is shown in the following link (https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=R9mvvylyUY0), then you should follow what I have described.

Comment: Yes this is what I want @Nikos BUT this guy manually selects the corners of the ad which determines the distortion/perspective. What I need is that the perspective needs to be determined automatically, if I were to choose the corners of the ad for every single frame depending on the camera position, then what's the points of doing this project? The ad needs to have correct distortion/perspective according to the camera position. That's why I need camera calibration and camera matrix.

Comment: Okay, I didn't understand that you wanted to do this for every frame in the video. Then what I would do is this. Firstly, calculate the homography the way I described for the first frame. Apply the transformation using [link] (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getperspectivetransform). Then, you should compute the homography for every frame starting from the homography between the 1st and 2nd frame, then the 2nd and the 3rd and so on. Each time you must apply this transformation to the already transformed image of the ad and place it on the frame.